# Can I implement a rules engine like Jess into Phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, system, rule, jess

I am soon beginning to develop a mobile application for my Final Year project in computer science. I am keeping my options open in regards what to use to create the application. I heard Phonegap is quite a handy API but can I still implement things such as [JESS rules](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/charlemagne.shtml)?

Comment: If you think of implementing anything that's a "thing such as JESS rules" on any platform whatsoever, your "Final Year" won't be your final year.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Apache Cordova now, Phonegap is a hosted build system (personally not a big fan of it, maybe it has improved now... anyway).

Using Cordova, you write the cross-platform application bits using JS, not Java.

So if you want to write something similar to JESS in JS this is possible and will give you a cross platform app.

I can imagine that calculations on rules might be computationally intensive so maybe not that suited for JS. In that case note that you can [write *plugins* for Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html) using other languages and call those from Javascript. But you will need to implement the plugin for iOS/Android/... separately using their respective toolkits.

Instead of using Cordova you can decide on Android/Java only. This should be easier and faster, albeit not cross platform. In that case, keep in mind that Dalvik (the android JVM) is not the same as stock JVM. This means that not every Java program can be run an Android without modifications.

HTH.